# Someone using my Apple ID to play Clash of Clans

Tags: apple-id, clash-of-clans

I downloaded Clash of Clans and I found that my Apple ID already had data. I change my password, but I found that this stranger still can play Clash of Clans with my account. How can I stop this?

Comment: how did you find out :)

Comment: i did not play the game before

Comment: Maybe enabling 2 factor authentication will log out the person using your account. Just visit https://appleid.apple.com to enable it.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the flood of similar problems we have seen today, one can say, it is they server having the problems.

There is nothing you can do other than wait till it is fixed.